# What is the best practice in production and development for .catch console error?

Tags: javascript, eslint

This is a snippet of my code:

```
const data = await fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      const payID = json.data.id
      sessionStorage.setItem('payID', payID)
      return true
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(`error: ${err}`))
```

What is your best practice? Do you retain the .catch in development and staging but remove it from PROD? Linter does not want console error in my code.

Comment: the last line could be written as `.catch(console.error)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Development: We use both an error visualizer like error modal + console/error-logger middleware.
2. In Staging & Production: We use only an error visualizer like modal because you will never expect a user or black-box-tester of the team(in case of testing staging deployment) to go to the console So, what is the use of consoling in production? Note, consoling in production might even be a leakage for hackers to know vividly what is going on. So, I will suggest never to console in staging/production, because anything that gets to staging means it will get to production once finished testing(so production and staging have the same rules).

So about the Eslint thingy, I will suggest you turn it off in the eslint file, and just be conscious of the rule of not putting unnecessary console. For me what I do before committing code for pull-request is to do: SHIFT + CTRL+ F and then type "console.log" to know which files have the console.log method in my VS-CODE and then I remove them.

Answer (score -3):

We can't leave a linter decide everything for us, I'd recommend leaving the `console.error` because most of the cases we need to see these errors in the console and read them, they exist for a reason.

And for the style of writing of course we can use the `point free` style

```js
.catch(console.error)
```

And for the linter, it most likely have a rule(at their documentation) to mute that error.